# codeigniter unix timestamp validate

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, unix-timestamp

I have unix timestamp input value. I have to validate whether input is correct timestamp format or not. Currently I'm using this:

```
$currenttime = $_POST['unixdate']; //input unix timestamp

if( $currenttime==strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:m:s',$currenttime) ) ){
    echo "Correct";
} else {
    echo "incorrect format";
}
```

I check this with several test cases, but its fail. Is that correct or is there any other way to check input is unix timestamp format or not?

Answer (score 1):

I timestamp is just an integer that represents the number of seconds passed since the epoch.  So the best validation you can do is something like

```
$currenttime = $_POST['unixdate']; //input unix timestamp

if((int)$currenttime == $currenttime && is_numeric($currenttime)) {
```

If you know what date you are expecting you could check to see if the timestamp falls between two dates or something like that

```
$startDate = '2014-10-04';
$endDate = '2013-10-04';

if((strtotime($currentDate) > strtotime($startDate)) && (strtotime($currentDate) < strtotime($endDate))) {
    //Is valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is incorrect because you compare with another date where you've replaced minutes with months:

```
'Y-m-d H:m:s'
   ^     ^
```

Other than that, it's quite a pointless validation. A Unix timestamp is nothing but a number (an integer if you want to be strict). Something like this should be enough:

```
$currenttime = filter_input(INT_POST, 'unixdate', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if($currenttime===false){
    // Invalid
}
```

Your method is like validating an age by trying to calculate the date of birth ;-)